# get the 100px area where the mouse is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have graph on web page so i want to add the zoom in/zoom out functionality.
my graph is inside the jquery tab. so when user want to zoom particular area of page inside the tab that should be zoom. 
For ex: when user double click on page and inside the tab to zoom 100px by 100px area shoud be zoom. Double click zoom in and single click zoom out

Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and where is your codes??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#targetDiv').on('dblclick',function() {
    $(this).width('100px');
    $(this).height('100px')
});

$('#targetDiv').on('click',function() {
    $(this).width('50px');
    $(this).height('50px')
});
```